# How to tell LaTeX to disable vertical padding?

Tags: spacing

I would like to write a small document with few lines per pages. Unfortunately, LaTeX put the title almost in the middle of the page with large spaces between the title and the paragraphs.

How to force LaTeX to pull all the text at the top of each page with no dynamic vertical spacing ?

Comment: Can you please make a small example? What document class are you using?

Comment: It's hard to make a small example, I have to reduce all my document and change the content. In this case LaTeX behave differently and I cannot reproduce this issue. I am using `article`.

Comment: title pages almost always have explicit spacing layout specific to the class, suppressing any  automatic spacing will not help if the `\maketitle` has explicit spacing such as the `\vspace{60pt}` at the start of the `article` class version.

Comment: If you cannot even provide an explicit example having this issue, why do you think that someone else will be able to guess what went wrong in a document that they do not have access to, and will be able to fix it?

Comment: You can just go and create a dummy document with your settings. The packages `duckuments` and `blindtext` both support this. In `duckuments` the macro is `\duckument`, in `blindtext` it's `\blinddocument`. So a small example could look like this `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{duckument}\begin{document}\title{Something}\author{Someone}\maketitle\duckument\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage{wordlike}`